# Word for multi opponent combat?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm googled it and cannot find an answer. I'm looking for a single word to describe multi opponent combat or multiple opponent training. Maybe even in the way of a skill. For example, a single person fighting multiple attackers at once. A single word....

Comment: How does "war" not fit?

Comment: A single person fighting multiple attackers at once.

Comment: How does "dead" not fit?

Comment: "Simultaneous attack" is the concept from the point of view of the attackers. I'm not sure if there is terminology that relates more directly to the defender.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Melee](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/melee)

> a confused hand-to-hand fight or struggle among several people.

Comment: Sometimes written *mêlée* to indicate pronunciation and origin. You would be dismayed at how many kids make this homophonic with *mealy*, and the diacritics can help steer them clear of that error.

Comment: I had considered melee, but always seen it used in a way that just means attack. Now after reviewing the definition of it from various sources, you are correct. This is what I'll use. Thanks!

Comment: @Xarcell it's been in my vocabulary since 1979 or so, as I used to play the  board game: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melee_(game)

Comment: @tchrist As I mentioned, I started to know the word because I played the game by the same name when I was in my teens. I always pronounced it "MAY-lay", but several people used the *mealy* homophone. Diacritics or not, where I grew up in West Virginia one wasn't always inclined to use fancy city-folk words.

Answer (score 1):

A **[Battle royal](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=battle%20royal)** is a fight involving three or more combatants, last fighter remains standing. This can include factions or be a free for all.

*American Heritage Dictionary*

Answer (score 0):

Fighting outnumbered? Not a single word but describes she situation pretty well. Also, taking on opponents one by one, if it's challenge-style.

Answer (score 0):

This may not satisfy your one word request but it fits well into the description required.

> A **One Man Army** is a heavily armed and well-trained soldier...
>   Usually he has enough muscles, brains, tactics and daring to face and
>   defeat countless enemies by himself, hence the term: a single soldier
>   who is worth an entire army due to his extreme combat competence.

[One Man army-Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Man_Army)

Hence multi opponent combat.